# Distinct value appearing more than once

Tags: sql, distinct

I am trying to show the unique value from Table B where it occurs on more than one occasion
[image]

Could someone help with this?
Here is my code but it is erroneous.
    SELECT DISTINCT * FROM B
    WHERE DISTINCT(Field1)>1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like

```
select field1, count(*) records
from b
group by field1
having count(*) > 1
```

Some details depend on your database engine which you did not specify.

Comment: This is all the information. There are 2 tables, so I made a representation of my 2 tables. It is actually a simple table with one column, and that ONE column is absurd from my view

Comment: Thank you. I am running a variation on the real table here. And it is running. No error being generated. Now my report will be complete.